# How to properly LEFT JOIN users with transactions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

```
   SELECT *
     FROM users
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.user_id
    WHERE payments.id = (SELECT max(p2.id) 
                           FROM payments p2 
                          WHERE payments.user_id = p2.user_id)
```

Is the query I am currently using to select the user info, as well as their last transaction. The problem is that I'd like to select the users even if they do not have a transaction in the database, how do I go about this?

My table structure I'm playing with is very simple:

```
USERS - user_id, name
PAYMENTS - id, user_id, method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off (performance wise) joining onto a sub query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users u
LEFT JOIN 
(Select user_id, max(id) from payments group by user_id) p
ON p.user_id = u.user_id
```

By putting any conditions in the Where clause, you are turning it into an inner join,

Comment: If you want to compare answers, have a look at the execution plan and test the two.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
SELECT users.*, payments.*
  FROM users
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.user_id
                  AND payments.id = (SELECT max(p2.id) 
                                       FROM payments p2 
                                      WHERE payments.user_id = p2.user_id)
```

You have two columns "user_id" in the result set, one from users table, and one from payments. The payments.user_id will be null, but users.user_id should have value.

Comment: This returns a blank user_id value for the user that has no transaction.

Comment: users.user_id should not be null, are you looking at payments.user_id?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Overlooked the first column. 
Enough staring at auto inc columns for a while now :P

Comment: Could you contrast your example against Mr. Shoulb's? Just trying to determine the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Why is everybody doing all that crazy stuff?

```
select u.user_id u_uid, u.name, p.user_id p_uid, p.method from users u left join payments p on (u.user_id = p.user_id);
```

Comment: This returns ALL payment rows. I only want the users with their last payment data appended.